# Best configuration for a low latency fast hidden service?

Tags: onion-services, speed

I set up a hidden service that serves a static low sized page but still it takes at least 20 seconds to open. Also sometimes it just closes itself when i am not around and doesn't respond for hours and i then need to restart Tor service.

My upload speed is 5 mbps is it related? I measured network usage and it doesn't even use 100 kbps. How can i speed up the service with configuration? And what is the reason service just shuts down and doesn't respond randomly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to minimize the code. If you use plain html with no javascript, no PHP, etc, it will be fastest and the most secure. Look into something like [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) or other static page generators for building extremely fast and secure sites.

Your internet speed isn't as important as your latency. If you ever play games online, you know what a pain it is to have high latency. The same goes for running an onion service on your network. If you are doing a lot on your network, expect your latency to go up.

Finally, know [how Tor works](https://2019.www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en). You will always go through at least 3 hops to get to your onion service. This will always cause lags and there is no way around this.

> And what is the reason service just shuts down and doesn't respond
>   randomly

No idea without you sharing more about your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you achieve something - you're always paying for that. Tor provides you an alternative routing way for the cost of speed, so - even serving a static pages out of Memcached+NGinx **will** pay it's toll for anonymity if the Tor routing chain is laggy. If you have to serve your fully static site fast - take a look at ZeroNet and IPFS - they're much more tailored ofr that task than Tor. Tor's primary purpose to provide *any* kind of service anonymously, not just a websites - so that's why it's not tailored for them.